# Visual Studio keyword highlighting in comments

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

Is there any way to highlight certain keywords like TODO in comments? I used to this feature in vim but can't find a way to do the same job in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I don't think so, the highlight is for the comment as a whole. I guess you could write a plug-in to do this but it might just be easier to refer to the Task List pane for your TODOs :)

Comment: TODOs in task list don't allow you to see any context. But highlighting in comments draws your attention to a certain part of code.

Comment: You can include necessary context in the TODO text, you can jump to the TODO by double-clicking the entry. Otherwise you are looking to scroll through your code looking for the highlighted TODO. I'm not necessarily saying that you are wrong, whatever works for you, I'm just saying it doesn't make sense to me. Given what you've said, I think you are on the 'write a plug-in' route, have a look at DXCore from DevExpress (www.devexpress.com), it's a free framework for integrating with the VS editor (it's used for CodeRush and Refactor Pro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ReSharper with Visual Studio, any comment with TODO or NOTE can be highlighted in a different colour.

Comment: and BUG is also a highlighting keyword