# How do I disable (or change) keyword highlighting in comments?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, syntax-highlighting

I am using Visual Studio 2008, and Resharper 5.0:

There are certain keywords such as `note`, `bug`, and `todo` that are highlighted within comments that I would like to disable or at least alter the highlight color and/or specify keywords.

However I can't find any settings in Visual Studio's Fonts and Colors options nor in Resharper's options to change this behavior.

Can anyone point out how and where this can be changed?

See this related question: [Visual Studio keyword highlighting in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714558/visual-studio-keyword-highlighting-in-comments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some more searching, I found that the options belong to Resharper, and are not intuitively placed within the options.

The settings are in the "To-do Items" under the Tools section, near the last of the list of options. There, "Patterns" and "Filters" determine what is found (Patterns) and how they are listed when you view To-do Items (Filters).

To disable a particular highlight, remove it from the Patterns. To add a new highlight or change an existing one, create or edit one.

This is a feature of Resharper that was quite difficult to find because I kept looking for "syntax highlighting" or "keyword highlighting" rather than "To-do items."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We'll see if there is a way we could improve it.